Can we consider dakshina Moorthy as my tantrik guru and do mantra japa without initiation?
I am looking for a guru for tantrik initiation but unable to find . Recently I came across a form of shiva called dakshina Moorthy who is said to be the adiguru of spiritual matters.
As I am unable to get an initiation but would like to chant some beejaksharas can I chant any stotram of dakshina Moorthy and consider him as my guru and chant the Beeja mantras?
